# Flask function decorator run at defintion time and call time?

Tags: python, authentication, flask, decorator, execution

I'm trying to implement a decorator function in Flask that does two things: register a page route and add some things to my DB on definition time, and then on runtime, when a request is made to a page it processes whether a user is authenticated.

I know that I can do these in two separate decorator functions, but this won't work because I eventually need to process the same set of information (app, rule, access groups, etc.) at both definition time and runtime.

The code below is what I have been messing with, but I have not been able to get it to work. It compiles and you are able to see "Definition time" in the console and "index" in the browser, but "Runtime" never gets printed. Can anyone suggest what I may be doing wrong?

```
from flask import Flask
from functools import wraps

app = Flask(__name__)


def register(app, rule, **options):
    def wrapper(f):
        print "Definition time"
        endpoint = options.pop('endpoint', f.__name__)
        access_groups = options.pop('access_groups', None)
        methods = options.get('methods', ['GET'])

        app.add_url_rule(rule, endpoint, f, **options)

        @wraps(f)
        def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
            print "Runtime"
            return f(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapped

    return wrapper


@register(app, '/', methods=['GET', 'POST'], access_groups=['all-access'])
def index():
    return "index"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: I tried this code out and it works as expected - can you clarify what it is you expect this code to do that it isn't doing?

Comment: @SeanVieira I've modified the code above. Try saving that into a file test.py and running python test.py, then going to localhost:5000 in your browser. It compiles and you are able to see "Definition time" in the console and "index" in the browser, but "Runtime" never gets printed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've added the original function in `add_url_rule`, not the wrapped function.  Move `add_url_rule` below `wrapped` and change the target.

```
def wrapped(...)
    ...

app.add_url_rule(rule, endpoint, wrapped, **options)
return wrapped
```

---

Here's the full code and the output on the console when run and accessed.

```
from functools import wraps
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

def register(app, rule, **options):
    def wrapper(f):
        print('Definition time')
        endpoint = options.pop('endpoint', f.__name__)
        access_groups = options.pop('access_groups', None)
        methods = options.pop('methods', ['GET'])

        @wraps(f)
        def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
            print('Runtime')
            return f(*args, **kwargs)

        app.add_url_rule(rule, endpoint, wrapped, **options)
        return wrapped

    return wrapper

@register(app, '/', methods=['GET', 'POST'], access_groups=['all-access'])
def index():
    return 'index'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

```
$ python example.py 
Definition time
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
Runtime
127.0.0.1 - - [04/Aug/2015 20:14:46] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```